# calling variables from external JFrames

Tags: java, variables, class, jframe

I have a Java game i'm creating and each window is a seperate JFrame
with its own components.

How would I get about calling variables from other .java programs?
Not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: By .java programs, do you mean classes in the same program (or JVM) or classes loaded into a separate instance of the JVM?

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A running JVM instance has no access to objects living in a different instance. Communication between java virtual machines has to be done with other means.

A practical way is to establish a TCP/IP based interface. One application acts as a server (opens a port) and listens to requests for data. TCP/IP based client/server solutions are not too complicated in Java.

Another rather simple alternative is using a shared file on the file system. The data provider updates this file on changes, the 'client' monitors this file and loads the content, whenever it detects update/change (monitor modification timestamp).

And to mention a third approach: [Java Management Extensions (JMX)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions) would help too. JConsole (part of the jdk) is a practical example on how to connect to a separate JVM and get access to ('public') data and methods.

Comment: The file-based solution, though wonderfully simple, sounds like it may run into trouble with processes overwriting each others' updates. The JMX idea, though, is very cool and elegant.

Comment: @Carl - JMX is my favorite too, but quite challenging ... beginners should start with files to have an early taste of success :)